# color the previous cell if the next cell has the value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to color the previous cell if the next cell has the VALUE "F".

Data must be in the one row, that's why I got a problem with that.

Conditional formating wont work in here maybe some macro. Does anyone know hot to solve that? Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Which is the range you need to be processed in the way you describe? Conditional formatting should work, but also `Worksheet_Change` event will deal with it. I mean, the left cell against the one being changed will be colored in green if the changed value is "F". But it would be good to limit the event range where to be triggered to the only one you need. The number of rows will be the existing rows in A:A, but what about the columns range?

Comment: Columns wont change. The range is like H6:BL6, H7:BL7, etc.

Comment: I was talking about the range where you need to trigger the event and change the left cell interior color, in case of "F". So, if I would say that the columns range is "H:BL" and the rows range will be all filled in "H:H" column, will it be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional formatting worked for me.  A basic example is shown below ...

[image: Example]

[image: Result]

Comment: Instead of the volatile `OFFSET` just use `=B1="F"` as formula if it is applied to a range that starts at `A1`. • If the applied range starts at `E5` then use `=F5="F"`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, copy the next code event in the respective sheet code module (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastR As Long, rng As Range
    lastR = Me.Range("H" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = Me.Range("H2:BL" & lastR) 'use here the columns range you need to process.
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "F" Then
            Target.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            Target.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```